# How do i set browser width/height on initiation and how can i add tabs at the start? ChromeDriver Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I have been struggling to adjust the browser width and height to be set during initialization. Currently i am using

```
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
options.add_argument("--width=300")
options.add_argument("--height=300")
driver.get(url)
...
```

This only opens the browser in its **default** size and then changes it to the size that i want after it is initiated. What i want is for it to open in the size given upon starting that task.

Secondly, is there a way for me to open up the browser window and then immediately add another tab? I tried using the Action Keys and also .send_keys but they both do not work as expected.

```
driver.get('www.google.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'T')
driver.get(page_address)
```

All this does is open google.com *after about 10 seconds* and then loads the page from `page_address`. I want it to not wait for that page to load full and to instantly open a new tab that will then load the page i tell it to from `page_address`.

I have also tried

```
driver.get('www.google.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'T')
driver.get(page_address)
```

If anyone has any idea please let me know. Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

using the ``execute_script``` allowed me to open a new tab almost instantly, although i feel like it would be faster if i can immediately change the size because that initiation seems to be slowing down the process. Here is the troubled code

```
            def startall():
                driver = []
                index = 0
                chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                for drive in range(0, num_tasks):
                    driver.append(webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options))
                for start_tasks in range(0, num_tasks):
                    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=300,300')
                    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
                    drivers = driver[index]
                    index = index + 1
                    drivers.execute_script("window.open('{}')".format(page_address))

            start_all = Button(page2, text='Start All', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14),
                               command=startall)
            start_all.place(x=900, y=5)
```

It is indented like this because of the amount of code and checks i am doing inside my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_window_size`() to reduce window size.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(300,300)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

OR you can use `chrome_options`().

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=300,300');
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

To open an new tab use `javscript` `executor`.

```
url="https://www.google.com"
driver.execute_script("window.open('{}')".format(url))
```

Comment: using both options (chrome options and set_window) still opens it initially in its standard size. Due to my code i also cannot copy and paste directly what you did in it becuase it wouldnt work. I have made an edit to the page to show the new code and hopefully you can pin point any errors i have made.

Comment: @mferraro : Have you seen how my chrome option added.You need to `add_argument()` with chrome_options before initialize the chrome driver.What you have done you have  initialized the chrome driver and then added the the `chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=300,300')` this is incorrect.

Comment: How can i reformat my code to represent this as i need to make a list of the drivers in the ```for drive in range(0, num_tasks):``` above the other loop that then executes them. Just adding the ```add_arguments``` to it simply doesnt work and makes the program act wrong.